# wcf windows integrated security

Tags: wcf, security, windows-authentication

I have active directory and several client computers joined the active directory.
In the client computers I have installed wcf clients.
On the server the wcf service is hosted in IIS.
I use message secyrity with windows credentials.

Everything is working fine.

But I have heard that there are some programs than can extract the password from windows (put live compact disk in the cdrom and restart the pc).

They can use the user and pass to access the wcf service from elsewhere and do damage.

Is this true and what steps can I take to be more safe ?

Regards

Comment: I can't say I have ever heard of this problem. I would have thought the only way you could get a password is from Active Directory itself and the only way you could do that (if even possible) is if you had domain controller access rights. I don't think this is a concern.

Comment: I think the client also stores the domain user and password because even if the active directory and domain controller are down the client can still log in to the client with domain credentials

Comment: (at least the xp caches the password)

Comment: this is interesting http://forums.whirlpool.net.au/archive/656047

Comment: And you think you can handle security in better way?

Comment: I found the solution. Disable the caching of domain accounts as in the link above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shiraz' advice is all valid for local (not AD) Windows accounts, but I believe the threat you're raising isn't related to the SAM-stored local Windows passwords, since you're talking about an Active Directory setup with Windows systems joined to the domain.

Presumably the message security/windows credentials only allows access to the user accounts you've setup in Active Directory.  [All discussion here assumes we're talking about those AD accounts, not local accounts on each Windows client.]

Assuming you've only allowed access to the WCF service for AD accounts, then the WCF service is only practically vulnerable to attackers who can retrieve (or guess) the plaintext password.  Since you raised the spectre of live CD attacks, I'll further assume you're only worried about attacks on the Windows clients and not on the AD domain controller (whose physical security is presumably much stronger than the physical protections of the Windows clients).

So the threat you're raising is the possibility that an attacker could somehow find the user's AD password somewhere on the hard drive of the Windows client (or an easily-broken equivalent of their password).  That is *not* the kind of attack for which the Live CDs are generally useful - as Shiraz indicated, they're good for digging up the password hashes out of the local SAM and helping to brute-force try many password combinations (or compare them to a local or online "rainbow table" that contains a ton of pre-calculated password values).  Some of these tools also scan through local caches of such passwords, such as older browsers that saved your password for web site authentication - though modern browsers pretty much all have avoided those plaintext backdoors now.

The main cache of a user's AD password on a Windows client is the "cached domain credentials" (which allows you to logon with your domain password even if you're not connected to the network).  This isn't stored as just a simple hash of your AD password - instead, it's doubly-hashed *and* encrypted with the local SYSKEY, making it an order of magnitude more time-consuming to try to brute force.  A reasonably long or strong (or both) AD password makes brute-force attacks pretty much infeasible except for very dedicated attackers (like espionage, governments, etc.)  So your most effective tool to make sure this is infeasible is to set a reasonable password policy - complex characters and a decent minimum length is fine; non-complex but very long passwords (aka passphrases) are also worthwhile.

Other caches of the password *might* exist, but that's dependent entirely on whether your users are using really crappy applications - there are fewer and fewer such applications on the market today, but never say never.

Answer (score 0):

This will depend on the version of windows and how updated it is. Previously there was a problem that you could boot the PC using a linux CD, then run a program that did a brute force attack on the SAM file that contained login information.

But the chances of this doing any damage are very small:

- It requires physical access to the machine
- It does not work with strong passwords
- It would require access to your office or that your service is open to the internet

To counter these threats:

- Require strong passwords
- Encrypt harddisks
- Block access to the service from the internet
- Protect your offices